# How to remove an object from an array in Perl

Tags: json, perl

I have a JSON string strcutred like so:
`[{"ip":"", "comment":""}, {"ip":"", "comment":""}]`

I'm trying to figure out how to remove one of these objects by identification from the IP and/or comment keys.

The closest i've got so far is this:

```
my $jsn = decode_json('[{"ip":"1.2.3.4", "comment":"one"}, {"ip":"10.10.10.10","comment":"two"}]');

foreach(@{$jsn}){
        if($_->{ip} eq '1.2.3.4'){
                print "Found!";
                splice @{$jsn}, $_, 1;
        }
}
```

I know splice doesn't work in this example. If i could get the index of the object (ideally without a counter), i think i could then remove the correct object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`grep` is your friend](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) here. It creates a new list of elements in an existing list that match an expression.

```
my @filtered = grep { $_->{ip} ne '1.2.3.4' } @$jsn;
```

Comment: writing back to the same array works as well, if one doesn't need/want to create a new one: `@$jsn = grep {...} @$jsn;`

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. I knew Perl could do something like this, neatly & one-liner style :)